# Replace tab with variable amount of spaces, maintaining the alignment

Tags: bash, awk, tabs, whitespace

I have a tab separated file, consisting of 7 columns.

```
ABC     1437    1       0       71      15.7    174.4
DEF     0       0       0       1       45.9    45.9
GHIJ    2       3       0       9       1.1     1.6
```

What I need is to replace the tab character with variable amount of space characters in order ot maintain the column alignment. Note that, I do **not** want every tab to be replaced by 8 spaces. Instead, I want 5 spaces after row #1 column #1 (8 - length(ABC) = 5), 4 spaces after row #1 column #2 (8 - length(1437) = 4), etc.

Is there a linux tool to do it for me, or I should write it myself?

Comment: Try: `column -t file`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, just had to provide `-s '  '` as well in order to get exactly the same visual output. Thanks!

Comment: `column` cannot produce the expected output since it just adds a fixed number of blanks between all columns where each column width is determined by the longest chain of non-blanks in that column. So it'll add 2 blanks (or whatever number you specify) between the end of `GHIJ` and the start of `2` on that last line of input but then it'll also use 2 blanks instead of 7 between `3` and `0` on that same line. It's a fine tool for creating visually tabular output but not for preserving the spacing from tab-separated input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POSIX utility [pr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) called as `pr -e -t` does exactly what you want and AFAIK is present in every Unix installation.

```
$ cat file
ABC     1437    1       0       71      15.7    174.4
DEF     0       0       0       1       45.9    45.9
GHIJ    2       3       0       9       1.1     1.6

$ pr -e -t file
ABC     1437    1       0       71      15.7    174.4
DEF     0       0       0       1       45.9    45.9
GHIJ    2       3       0       9       1.1     1.6
```

and with the tabs visible as `^I`s:

```
$ cat -ET file
ABC^I1437^I1^I0^I71^I15.7^I174.4$
DEF^I0^I0^I0^I1^I45.9^I45.9$
GHIJ^I2^I3^I0^I9^I1.1^I1.6$

$ pr -e -t file | cat -ET
ABC     1437    1       0       71      15.7    174.4$
DEF     0       0       0       1       45.9    45.9$
GHIJ    2       3       0       9       1.1     1.6$
```

Answer (score 3):

There is command pair dedicated for this task.

```
$ expand file
```

will do exactly what you want.  The counterpart `unexpand -a` to do the reverse.  There are few other useful options in both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `column`, as suggested in the comment by *anubhava*, specifically using `-t` and `-s` options:

```
column -t -s $'\t' in_file
```

From the [column manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html):

```
   -s, --separator separators
          Specify the possible input item delimiters (default is
          whitespace).

   -t, --table
          Determine the number of columns the input contains and
          create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by
          default, or with the characters supplied using the
          --output-separator option.  Table output is useful for
          pretty-printing.
```

Comment: That would not produce the expected output. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050075/replace-tab-with-variable-amount-of-spaces-maintaining-the-alignment#comment116780816_66050075) under the question.