# tabulated output with carriage return with jq

Tags: json, jq, tabular

I'm tryng to get a tabulated output with jq, but I can't get the alignement perfect. See:

```
$ ./Error_CLIENT.sh | /home/USER/jq -rj '.[] | .job.Name, "\t\t" ,.Atrributes.userData, "\n"'
HOME22          pte
HOME23          pte
HOUSEABI                pdt all
HOUSEAB2                pdt all
....
```

I would like to get:

```
HOME22                  pte
HOME23                  pte
HOUSEABI                pdt all
HOUSEAB2                pdt all
.......
```

Do you know if it's possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A jq-only solution is certainly possible, but it would almost certainly be much easier to use jq’s `@tsv` in conjunction with  `column -t` or perhaps `pr -e`; see e.g. [Replace tab with variable amount of spaces, maintaining the alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050075/replace-tab-with-variable-amount-of-spaces-maintaining-the-alignment)

Comment: I'm trying with these: ./Error_CLIENT.sh | /home/USER/parser -rj '[.[] | .job.Name, "\t\t" ,.Atrributes.userData, "\n"] |@tsv'
But it gets me: HOME22  pte       \n      HOME23  pte       \n      HOUSEABI        pdt all       \n      HOUSEAB2        pdt all       \n   ...
It shows me character literal "\n"